# Rest API calls in Typescript are failing with vscode veresion 1.82.2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

On making Rest API calls in Typescript I am getting below error
error code : 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
message: 'unable to get local issuer certificate'

Our API Calls were working fine till vscode version 1.81.1

With vscode 1.82.2 , If I  set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0  (on command prompt) then API calls works fine but this step skips the SSL certificate verification process which is not recommended.
What needs to be done to resolve UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY with vscode version 1.82.2?

- VS Code Version: 1.82.2
- OS Version: Windows 11 Enterprise

Comment: The error states the issue, the SSL certificate cannot be verified. Check out this article: https://cheapsslweb.com/blog/fixing-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally-error I hope you figure it out!

Comment: I have already tried blog as you listed .
My question is What is the change in vscode version 1.82.1/1.82.2 compared to 1.81.1 related to SSL certificate verification/validation?
Because everything was working fine with vscode version 1.81.1 but stopped working from 1.82.1.
So how to resolve error UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY without compromising on the SSL certificate validation?

Answer (score 0):

Revert VS Code version back to 1.81.1.

You should be good to revert back. Here are all the 1.82.1/1.82.2 release docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82

I will say the 1.82.1 update does address a single security issue with maliciously crafted `package.json`/`.npmrc` files. See link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22August+2023+Recovery+1%22+is%3Aclosed

However, this probably doesn't pertain to you.

---

Note: I looked for changes to the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` in the release docs, nothing comes up. It looks like nothing changed, meaning there may have been something on your side. Some common trouble shooting may fix issue:

- Clean install of vs code
- Make sure VS Code system configurations are correct
- Look through API code for potential CORS issues? (Don't have much to go on from your question, but the API code doesn't sound like the problem)